# Eslint / Prettier Ignoring files with .mock extension

Tags: eslint, tsconfig, prettier-eslint

I am using Angular with Eslint and Prettier configured for the entire project. All the files are checked correctly according to rules. Unfortunately, the files that have `.mock` in name are completely ignored. The file is called for example `test.mock.ts` and is ignored by Eslint/Prettier. If I rename it to `test.mocks.ts` or anything else without the `mock` keyword, it starts to work.

Does anyone know why it behave like this?

Eslint config file:

```
{
  "extends": ["prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"]
  },
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        ...some rules...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "@generated/*": [
        "libs/shared/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your mock files inside projects folder? Also, what is you tsconfig file like?

Comment: Files are in the project folder.. as I said, when I rename them, it starts to work. so the problem is clearly with naming only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had in .eslintignore file rule to ignore all .mock files.